# Updating more than one row with a single query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have a table called `posts` in my database with a column called `has_read`. I then have an array of post IDs like so:

`$posts = array(1, 5, 29, 38, 50, 51, 52, 65, 79);`

What I want to do is for all of those posts in the array, update their row to add the user ID to `has_read`. I can't use a foreach loop because it'll execute 9 queries, which I think is too much.

Comment: You could use the IN operator like UPDATE table SET has_read=1 WHERE id IN(1, 5, 29, 38, 50, 51, 52, 65, 79)

Comment: `UPDATE posts SET has_read=<userID> WHERE postID IN (1, 5, 29, 38, 50, 51, 52, 65, 79)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$updatestring = implode(",",$posts = array(1, 5, 29, 38, 50, 51, 52, 65, 79))

$sql = "UPDATE post SET has_read=1 WHERE userID IN($updatestring)";
```

Concat your array of id's to a comma separated string and just use the IN() function for a bulk update

Although actually thinking about it this is the completely wrong way of doing this.  Since its a one thread to many users relationship you're better off having a normalised database for this and using a separate table to track reads based off userid and thread id.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `WHERE IN` statment like this :

```
$result = mysql_query('UPDATE table SET field = value WHERE id IN ('.implode(',',$posts).')');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use IN.

```
$sql = "UPDATE posts 
        SET has_read = has_read + " . $user_id . "
        WHERE id IN (" . implode(",", $posts) . ")";
```

Of course, you should not literally do it this way, but prepare a statement and pass the $user_id as a parameter, depending on the database library you are using.

Answer (score 0):

use `Where` with `IN`

```
$result = mysql_query('UPDATE posts SET has_read= user_id
WHERE id IN ('.implode(',',$posts).')');
```

Answer (score 0):

What about something like:

```
UPDATE posts_table SET has_read = 1 WHERE id IN (1, 5, 29, 38, 50, 51, 52, 65, 79);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$query = 'UPDATE posts SET has_head = 1 WHERE id IN (' . implode(',', array_map('intval', $array)) . ');';
```